# Remove character from backrefrence after using re.sub

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string with a list of usernames mentioned for instance:

`s = '@romeo went to @juliet and said hi, I'm @romeo'`

I want to replace that username patter with links to user profile which should become `<a href="/u/username">@username</a>`
I am now able to replace the patterns, however, I cannot seem to get rid of the  `@`  in the `href` with using backreferences.

`print(re.sub(r"(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,31})", r'<a href="/u/\g<0>">\g<0></a>', s))`

That right now prints:

`<a href="/u/@romeo">@romeo</a> went to<a href="/u/ @juliet"> @juliet</a> and said hi, Im<a href="/u/ @romeo"> @romeo</a>`

Which now you can see the extra space and `@`  I cannot seem to get rid of that after using the regex

Comment: `\g<0>` is full match, you need `\1` in the first case. Also, you have `s = "@romeo went to @juliet and said hi, I'm @romeo"`, not `s = '@romeo went to @juliet and said hi, I'm @romeo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```py
print(re.sub(r"\B(?<!@)@(\w{1,31})", r'<a href="/u/\1">\g<0></a>', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wOX4z7) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1oIaNC/1).

**Regex**

- `\B@` - `@` char either at the start of string, or when immediately preceded with a non-word char
- `(?<!@)` - the preceding `@` should not be immediately preceded with `@`
- `(\w{1,31})` - Capturing group 1 (`\1`): one to thirty-one word chars.

The `\1` in `r'<a href="/u/\1">\g<0></a>'` stands for the Group 1 value. `\g<0>` stands for the whole match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now it works however, I do not seem to understand what is the issue with the current regex that I am using?

Comment: @ashes999 It is more efficient in Python `re` to first match on something static, like word boundary, letter, digit, not alternation group. Besides, `(...)` creates an extra group, that is extra overhead.